# Rounding issue: Sometimes rounding down instead of up for decimal values that end in 5

Tags: rounding

After using a proprietary language for some time, I have noticed that some values when rounded to two places/three places, round incorrectly.

Examples: 4.055 rounding to 4.05, 2.495 rounding to 2.49

I understand that this may be an issue with the precision, but I am unsure as to how to predict when the rounding issue will occur. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `4.055` isn't really stored internally as `4.05499`, which correctly rounds down?

Comment: I presume that is what is happening. However I'm unsure as to why some inputs are being stored this way and others are not. Do you have an explanation for that? I will implement the answer by Code4R7 below